# Unexpected token { with Webpack 4 and @babel/preset-env

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-preset-env

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Here's where the error comes from. \client\src\components\AddBook.js:

`const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;`

The error message

```
   11 |   }
   12 |
 > 13 |   const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
      |         ^
   14 |
   15 |   const handleSubmit = (allValues) => {
   16 |     console.log('formData:', allValues);
```

I thought `@babel/preset-env` took care of all the latest JavaScript syntax. What does make the code break?
The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklist

Answer (score 2):

Your `.babelrc` does not explicitly define which **browsers/versions** it is supposed to transpile code for.

Adjust the following sample `.babelrc` to your needs:

```
{ 
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [ "last 1 version", "ie >= 11" ]
      },
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ]
}
```

> https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets

Also when using webpack you need to tell `babel-loader` explicitly to respect `.babelrc` and where it is located.

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
options: {
  babelrc: path.join(process.cwd(), './babelrc')
}
```

, assuming `.babelrc` is located in your project's root directory.

Comment: Thank you. I've adjusted `.babelrc` to `{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "Firefox >= 50"]
        }
      },
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ]
}` I'm on Firefox 50. Now getting `[1]   3 | import App from './components/App';
[1]   4 |
[1] > 5 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
[1]     |                 ^` It complains about `<` in `<App />`.

Comment: Does this has to do with `loader: 'babel-loader'` in the webpack config?

Comment: You need to tell `babel-loader` explicitly to respect `.babelrc` and where it is located. `loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    babelrc: path.join(process.cwd(), './babelrc')
  }`, asumming `.babelrc` is in your project's root directory.